# Making 2d grids in ruby and solving the puzzle

Tags: ruby, math, grid

I am very interested in learning to code in Ruby simply because I would like to get into web developing but I also have a small side project that I actually calculated on the paper manually.

I was making a square and simply counting ways that you can go from the top left point towards the bottom right point while only going right and down.

Now in 1x1 grid there are only 2 solutions.
When you make a 2x2 grid you are actually making 4 squares (or one big 1x1 grid size of 2 but you then split it in half on both sides)

The answer on this puzzle is 6.

And so I was going for 3x3, 4x4 etc. and calculating manually. Why I did all that you might ask? Well I was actually looking for a sequence of numbers that I would input into the integer sequence database (oeis.org) and was trying to find the mathematical formula for this puzzle. It was a success however I wanted to go further by simply changing the rules for example you can't move more then twice towards the right, or down.. or maybe you could move left only once and so on.

Then I realized that calculating all the possibilities manually would be very difficult so I decided to try and make a code that would bruteforce it.

I understand that Ruby might not be the best language for this (maybe c++?) but I am really interested in Ruby and would like to solve this problem using this language.

The problem is I have no idea where to start :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to move 2*n times for a n-size grid, n times **l**eft and n times **d**own. In how many ways can you combine lldd, ldld, lddl etc.? [Here](http://www.ohrt.com/odds/binomial.php) is a website specific for these calculations: C(4,2) for a 2x2 grid, C(6,3) for 3x3 etc. Google for binomial coefficient to find out how to calculate them yourself. Don't do it for [oeis](https://oeis.org/A000984) though.

Comment: Yes but what if I want to change the rules of the puzzle? For example you can only move in a certain direction only twice, the third time you have to move in some other direction. Or what if I propose some other rules?